# ES2020 private class methods/fields and testing

Tags: testing, methods, jestjs, private, ecmascript-2020

As you may know, **ES2020** is introducing private class methods and fields, similar to what we have currently in typescript
(albeit a different keyword... TS -> private | JS -> #methodName or #fieldName).

**Link to the RC (stage 3)**:
https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-methods

We can currently use this with a **babel plugin**:
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-private-methods

**Tech stack:**

I work with Jest and Enzyme for unit testing.

**The problem:**

The issue I'm facing is that whenever I import a class using these fields or methods and I simply try to reference the wrapper.instance() calling them to test them, I can see that the private method is not visible in the instance (which is correct, since it's private).

An example error: `#someMethod is undefined`

How would you go on approaching this?

Would you skip testing the private methods or is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While debugging my UT I saw that they get a prefix to their names of `__private_XXX_` when XXX is their "index" of appearance in the class.

so you can access `#someMethod` by using `__private_XXX_someMethod` but that requires you to check that "index" and to update it every time the class changes the indexes.